# Replace capital letters in an entire string with lowercase letters and hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace the capital letters in an entire string with their lower case counter parts while adding hyphen after it (unless its the last letter). So that `Sunny&Cloudy` would be come `sunny-&-cloudy`

```
var name = 'Sunny&Cloudy';
name.replace(/([A-Z])(.*)/, '\L$1');
```

I've tried this this myself but it only reaches the first capital letter adds a hyphen and stops. Leaving me with `-S`

Comment: But `&` is not a capital letter. Why do you want a hypen after it? Why noy `sunny-&c-loudy`?

Comment: Which part of your code adds the hyphen?

Comment: name.toLowerCase().replace(/&/g, "-&-")

Comment: Can you add other examples so we can understand what you need to do in other scenarios?

Comment: Hello, can you further explain where do you want to add the hyphen? Would they appear at the end of each word? Will all words have a & in between them? Thanks !

Comment: @GOTO0 Sorry I guess that was a bad example. I was hoping to actually replace `&` with with `and` once I had something to work with. Is it possible to give `&` the same treatment as the capital letters?

Comment: So, your goal is to replace `Sunny&Cloudy` by `sunny and cloudy`?

Comment: @DiegoTArg Hoping to replace every capital letter with a lower case letter and add a hyphen after that word. I have no idea how to use regex so I'm wondering if what I want is even possible.

Comment: @Shidersz Yea exactly but the spaces should be hyphens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert `Sunny&Cloudy` into `sunny-&-cloudy`, then the following code should work:

```
var name = 'Sunny&Cloudy';
name.replace(/[A-Z][a-z]*/g, str => '-' + str.toLowerCase() + '-')
  // Convert words to lower case and add hyphens around it (for stuff like "&")
  .replace('--', '-') // remove double hyphens
  .replace(/(^-)|(-$)/g, ''); // remove hyphens at the beginning and the end
```

Basically you just use a `function` as the second parameter of `.replace`. ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters))

It's not only replacing capitalized letter with their lowercase counterpart though, so you might want to revise your question description.

Comment: This works well! I just added `.replace('&', 'and')` to change the `&` to `and` aswell :) Cheers!

Comment: By the way, if you have numbers in your words, you may need to add `0-9` in the regex to make it `[a-z0-9]` (and maybe `[A-Z0-9]` if numbers can be the first letter, but that will make it tricky to separate words), or use word boundaries as someone posted in one answer below.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach for what you need is to use the [replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) of [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
var name = 'Sunny&Cloudy';

let res = name.replace(/[A-Z&]/g, m => m === "&" ? "-and-" : m.toLowerCase());

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use word boundaries `\b` to split the string into tokens, map everything to lowercase (except the last letter) and join the result together with a - dash

```js
function dashed(str, sep) {
  let words = str.split(sep);
  return words.map(word => {
    let left = word.slice(0, -1).toLowerCase();
    let lastLetter = word.slice(-1);
    return `${left}${lastLetter}`
  }).join('-')

}

console.log(
  dashed("Sunny&CloudY&Rainy", /\b/)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should do the trick:

```
const regex = /(.+?\b)+?/g;
const str = 'Sunny&Cloudy&rainy';
const subst = '$1-';
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

//make string lowercase + remove last '-'
console.log('Substitution result: ', result.toLowerCase().substring(0, result.length - 1));
```

By the way [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) can come in handy to perfect a regex. You can select the 'ECMAScript/JavaScript' regex option. I use that site whenever I need to create a regex.